# How to get extended User custom fields in django template?

Tags: django

I have extended django builtin user model. I am currently using django 1.10.

I am trying to display user name, short_name in template.
note: short_name is extended field

```
<span> {{ request.user.profile.username  }} </span>
<span> {{ user.profile.username  }} </span>
{{ user.get_username }}
{{ user.username }}
```

this template tag is not working for django 1.10

I have used this link for creating custom user model https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

using this I would like to display role based content.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    access = (
        ('admin', 'admin'),

        ('director', 'director'),
        ('management', 'management'),
        ('employee', 'employee'),
    )
    access_control = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=access)
    YES_NO = (
        ('yes', 'Yes'),
        ('no', 'No'),
    )
    active = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=YES_NO)
```

> Added below lines in settings:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "user_login.UserProfile"

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `ForeignKey` as relation with `user`, you CAN'T access it via `user.userprofile.short_name`, if you don't have defined `related_name` in your field, you would get it by `user.userprofile_set.first().short_name`, now, you can change the relation type to `OneToOneField` and use as `user.userprofile.short_name`, in this way only works with onetoone relation

Comment: I have migrated models to user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) But even now its not working for me even {{ request.user.username }} this not working. Do I need to send anything more than context to template?

Comment: must be `{{ request.user.userprofile.short_name }}`, if you use `{{ request.user.username }}` you're reffering to username field of User model

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the relation from User to UserProfile is called `userprofile`.

Secondly, `username` is on the main User model; your extra field is called `short_name`. So:

```
{{ user.userprofile.short_name }}
```

Comment: {{ user.userprofile.short_name }} is not working for me, may be problem in my settings

Comment: As German points out, you have a ForeignKey not a OneToOneField. That doesn't make sense, you should change it to a one-to-one, then this syntax will work.

Answer (score 0):

The username field is in the user model, so things like `{{ request.user.profile.username  }}` should be `{{ request.user.username }}`. Your profile model is called UserProfile and you do not specify a reverse relationship name, so by default it will be called `userprofile`, so `{{ user.userprofile.short_name }}`, not `{{ user.profile.short_name }}`. And keep in mind, that to use any object inside your templates, you need to pass it in the context.